# Create bash file to open minecraft launcher

Tags: command-line, bash, java, minecraft

I use this command in the terminal to run the minecraft launcher with java 8:

```
/home/max/Java/jre1.8.0_25/bin/java -jar Minecraft.jar
```

I included the full java path because I installed it on `/home` as a normal user and i want to include it.

That command works, it opens the launcher with Java 8 but I want to make a bash file so I don't have to open the terminal. And, most important, I don't want the terminal to remain open when I click play in the Minecraft launcher and the game starts.

Now if i close manually the terminal when the game have started, the game is closed too.

Comment: I personally look forward to the advice you receive.  It has been my impression that if a bash file began it, the terminal will remain open as long as the program is running.  Were it not for that one condition, I could have answered this question myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using linux you probably like to see different ways of "living".
I suggest you the hard way:

1. open a terminal (I can not survive with less than 3 terminals opened) and keep it opened! And learn how to do everything with commands.
2. create a `~/bin` directory for your commands (`mkdir ~/bin`)
3. add `~/bin` the PATH
4. create a command named minecraft (using @Sudheer, using an editor or by

   ```
   echo -e '#!/bin/bash'
   /home/max/Java/jre1.8.0_25/bin/java -jar Minecraft.jar' > ~/bin/minecraft
   chmod 755 ~/bin/minecraft
   ```
5. instead of clicking, just write `minecraft` in your terminal.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a **.desktop** file that will do this. Bash file are usually run from the terminal, while .desktop files simply run a command, not necessarily needing a Terminal.

As for launching Minecraft, that's simple enough.

1. Run `nano ~/.local/share/applications/minecraft.desktop` in Terminal
2. Copy/paste this in to the file you just opened:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Comment="Launching Minecraft"
   Terminal=false
   Name=Minecraft Launcher
   Exec=/home/USER/Java/jre1.8.0_25/bin/java -jar ~/Minecraft.jar
   Type=Application
   Icon=/home/USER/.minecraft/mc_logo.png
   ```
3. Save and close that file
4. Save this image in your `~/.minecraft` folder as `mc_logo.png`:

   [image: logo]

And you should be able to find this in the dash and launch Minecraft without the Terminal!

Comment: Does `~` work directly in a launcher file?

Comment: @muru It should. If not, simply replace it with `/home/USER`.

Comment: @muru Huh, I guess I've never had an issue with this. If that's truly what the standard is, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: It's a common enough question here (getting `~`, `$BLAH`, etc, to work in launcher files). Here's the standard, if you need: http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables. In particular: "If an argument contains a reserved character the argument must be quoted." and "Reserved characters are ... tilde ("~")..."

Comment: @muru Ah, thank you for pointing this out! I haven't done a whole  lot with launcher files, so I didn't know. I've fixed it :D

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Ubuntu.

I am guessing you're using the latest version of Minecraft launcher(the new Minecraft launcher since Minecraft 1.6) with the title `Minecraft Launcher 1.5.3)right?

With the command you state above, it will only start Minecraft launcher with Java 8 instead of Minecraft(the game) with Java 8.

If you want to launch Minecraft with Java 8, launch Minecraft launcher as usual. Next, click on `Edit Profile` button. You will see a dialog. Under `Java Settings (Advanced)`, tick the `Executable` checkbox and put in the path to Java 8. Click `Save Profile` and you're done!

@Ubuntu4Life, you are advised to always use **latest** version of Java. Mojang also advises everyone to use latest version of Java to play Minecraft for performance boosts and a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can follow @RPI_Awesomeness and create a desktop icon it's easy to access from dash search. If you want to create a bash file then

1. Create a empty document on your desktop and paste the whole command in it.
2. Right click & goto properties make it executable.

That's it now double click and select run.