# How do I run minecraft using a command

Tags: command-line, minecraft

I am using SSR to record and I chose the option "record an opengl game" and I'm wondering what I put in the command spot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you launch Minecraft.

I'll provide solutions for the two most common methods, that way other people can benefit as well.

---

### Generic Steps - either method of launching must follow these

The following steps are generic and work for whatever method you launch Minecraft by, they're simply how you set up SimpleScreenRecorder to record OpenGL

1. Start up SimpleScreenRecorder. You obviously need to have it installed, so do that.
2. Set it up as follows (ignoring the **Profile** title - that's just my custom profile):

   You need to select **Record OpenGL (experimental)**, then set the FPS you want to record at - 30 FPS & 60 FPS are what most Youtubers use.

   Anything above 60 FPS is just wasted and harder to work with, since you can only upload to Youtube in up to 60 FPS.

   [image: recording settings]

---

## Method 1: Launching via Minecraft Peep's launcher

If you installed Minecraft/run Minecraft via [Minecraft Peep's launcher](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/minecraft-installer-for-ubuntu), this is fairly simple.

Since you can launch Minecraft from the terminal via the command `minecraft`, you simply put that in for the command:

### Minecraft Peep's-specific steps:

1. Install Minecraft Peep's Minecraft Launcher (works in 12.04 through 14.04) via:

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:minecraft-installer-peeps/minecraft-installer`

   and then

   `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install minecraft-installer`.

   This *should* install the launcher and make it so you can launch Minecraft via the program in the launcher and via the command `minecraft`. **Note**: You'll still need to [install Java](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java) to run Minecraft.
2. After installing the Minecraft Peep's launcher and setting up SimpleScreenRecorder for OpenGL recording (detailed above), click on <kbd>OpenGL settings...</kbd> and set the next windows as such:

   [image: opengl settings]

   You need to type in `minecraft` in the command text box and then select **Launch Automatically**.
3. Record! You can set the rest of the parameters as you like.

## Method 2: Launching via `java -jar` command

This is probably the most common way that people launch Minecraft on Ubuntu, by downloading the `Minecraft.jar` file and launching it manually either in the terminal or by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

### Manually launching-specific steps:

1. Download the `Minecraft.jar` file from [the Minecraft website](https://minecraft.net/download). You'll also [need to install Java](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java).
2. Put the jar wherever you want. The place where you launch it from won't change how it works (unless it's stored on an external HDD or USB stick.) I personally just leave it in my `/home/USER/Downloads` folder where I downloaded it to.

   Just remember where it's stored.
3. After downloading the `Minecraft.jar` file from the site and setting up SimpleScreenRecorder for recording OpenGL (detailed above) click on <kbd>OpenGL settings...</kbd> and set the next windows as such:

   [image: opengl settings]

   If you simply downloaded the `Minecraft.jar` file you can just enter into the command text box the following:

   `java -jar ~/Downloads/Minecraft.jar`

   and it should work!

   If you moved the downloaded `Minecraft.jar` file, you'll need to enter `java -jar` followed by the full path to the file.
4. Record! You can set the rest of the parameters as you like.

Comment: I would highly suggest the Java -jar method. This allows you to directly use java to launch, and give you flexibility in that you can set your initial and max memory to allocate to java.

Comment: What if you created your own shell script to launch via the java command? Can you simply add the shell script to the Launch Application section?

Comment: @IanM FYI, you can do that within the launcher as well. Just edit the profile :) It's actually better if you do it that way, because if you launch the launcher (`Minecraft.jar`) with the memory arguments it might not apply to the actual minecraft application - since the launcher is just that: A program that **launches** the actual minecraft .jar. Just go into `Edit Profile` on the launcher and you can set the Java args. However, I could be wrong, and args sent to the launcher *might* carry through to the actual game.

Comment: @JRSofty Yes, that's a possible. Someone actually asked about that specifically. [Look here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/565149/create-bash-file-to-open-minecraft-launcher), there are several different solutions listed.

Comment: I'd vote up but I dont have 15 reputation! :)

Comment: @ThugGaming Thanks :) You can edit other people's questions and answers if they need improvement in grammar or formatting - that's +2 rep if your edit gets accepted! It's how I got a bunch of my rep before hitting 2k :)